# insertSeparators not displaying separator above item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3

I'm using Paging 3 and trying to use the insertSeparators method to "group" my API response by score, an Int.

Something like this, inserting the separators with the value above the items with the same value.

[image]

Or like this:

```
   Separator 32000
      Item Movie 32000
      Item Movie2 32000
      Item Movie3 32000
   Separator 31433
      Item Movie 31433
      Item Movie2 31433
   Separator 28755
      Item Movie 28755
      Item Movie2 28755
      Item Movie3 28755
      Item Movie4 28755
```

My API call response is sorted by this score.
This is what I tried:

```
 .map {
        it.insertSeparators{ after, before ->
            if (before == null) {
                return@insertSeparators null
            }

            if (after == null) {
                return@insertSeparators null
            }
         
            //score is an int
         
            if (after.score > before.score ) {
                MovieModel.Header(before.score))
            } else {
                // no separator
                null
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how its displayed right now, the separator is going under the item:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, here it is the code:

```
.map {
        it.insertSeparators{ after, before ->
          

            if (after == null) {
                return@insertSeparators null
            }
            if(before == null){
                MovieModel.Header(after.score)
            }

         
            if (before.score != after.score ) {
                MovieModel.Header(after.score))
            } else {
                // no separator
                null
            }
        }
    }
```